# FreeBSD 10 root certificate store

Tags: freebsd, ssl, certificates

Is on a default FreeBSD 10 no root certificate store?

When I install one by hand it is in `/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt`, which I symlink to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` and thats the main places I search for it. Without luck.

Is there no default root certificate store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no default certificate store. There is a README file under `/usr/src/crypto/openssl/certs`, that states that

> The OpenSSL project does not (any longer) include root CA certificates.
>
> Please check out the FAQ:
>     * How can I set up a bundle of commercial root CA certificates?

The FAQ in question can be found [here](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#USER16), and basically says that the OpenSSL project doesn't have a policy on what CAs to include or exclude. Installing the `security/ca_root_nss` port is the best thing to do, if you need a CA store. Indeed, many ports depend on it, so it's probably installed on a high proportion of FreeBSD systems.